# {"error":"Error parsing request: missing request parameter"} In Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ksqldb

I'm currently facing an issue while trying to connect Node.js with KSQL. I have a KSQL table that I can query successfully using KSQL, but when I attempt to connect to it from Node.js using the ksqlExample.js file, I encounter an error.

Here's a simplified version of my ksqlExample.js file:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const serverUrl = 'ws://localhost:8088/ws/query';
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Test_transactionWithkeytableQueryable;';
const ws = new WebSocket(serverUrl);
ws.on('open', () => {
ws.send(query);
});
ws.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data);
});
ws.on('error', (error) => {
console.error(error);
});
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Test_transactionWithkeytableQueryable;';
executeKsqlQuery(query);
```

When I executed the script node ksqlExample.js, the response I received was in the form of a buffer:

```
<Buffer 7b 22 65 72 72 6f 72 22 3a 22 45 72 72 6f 72 20 70 61 72 73 69 6e 67 20 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 3a 20 6d 69 73 73 69 6e 67 20 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 20 70 ... 10 more bytes>
```

To convert the buffer to a string, I used the data.toString() method. However, after applying this change, I encountered the following error message:

```
{"error":"Error parsing request: missing request parameter"}
```

The updated script with the toString() method is as follows:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const serverUrl = 'ws://localhost:8088/ws/query';
const query = 'SELECT * FROM Test_transactionWithkeytableQueryable;';
const ws = new WebSocket(serverUrl);
ws.on('open', () => {
ws.send(query);
});
ws.on('message', (data) => {
console.log(data.toString());
});
ws.on('error', (error) => {
console.error(error);
});
```

I have verified that the table name (Test_transactionWithkeytableQueryable) and the KSQL server URL (http://localhost:8088) are correct. The table is queryable using KSQL, so it seems to be an issue specific to connecting from Node.js.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions to overcome this issue.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.